# Reading LocalStorage with BotFramework

Tags: botframework, bots, factory-bot

I need to integrate a bot with sharepoint, but one of the main features is that when user need to interact with the bot, the bot must know who users is talking to him.
The user is previusly logged in the sharepoint site, so i need a way to let bot to know who is the users that is talking to jhim, i thought to use localstorage, but i dont know who to make a bot read values from localstorage in .net, anyone knows?, 
Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: please add relevant code

Comment: How are you implementing the integration? Is this a webchat bot in a referenced from a webpart/iframe? or are you integrating webchat through a SPFx solution? or something else?